# Currying: Get a callable object even when applying all arguments

Tags: python, currying

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
from pymonad.Reader import curry

@curry
def fun_ab(a, b):
  return fancy_stuff_with_ab(a, b)

f = fun_ab(a, b) # Function is called...
# ...while I'd actually like to have a function object with all args bound:
f()
```

I do *currying* but when I apply all arguments, I'd still like to get a function object and not yet have the function called because the functions acts as a parameter to another function.

**An option would be to use lambda, another one to use partial - but what is the most elegant way to achieve what I want?**

Comment: How do you mean *elegant*? I think  a `lambda` or `functools.partial` are elegant.

Comment: If you don't like writing `partial` all over the place, the solution is to roll your own function decorator to hide it